# UpdateListItems method from SharePoint Lists Web Service fails with a Soap Server Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, sharepoint

I'm developing a MS Office 2010 Excel AddIn from a client machine which doesn't have SharePoint installed in it. I imported a Lists web service reference from a remote SharePoint server. I developed a wpf user control which can load data from the list and show it in the excel worksheet. It works perfectly. Then I extend my client application to update list items in the server. So I tried to update list items in the server with UpdateListItems method using the web service reference.

But it failed with an exception "Soap Server Exception.". I can't figure out what's wrong here as I can import data without any problem. Following is my code block.

```
SPListsWS.Lists myListUpdateProxy = new SPListsWS.Lists();
        myListUpdateProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        myListUpdateProxy.Url = "http://uvo1y1focm66gonf7gw.env.cloudshare.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

        XmlNode listView = myListUpdateProxy.GetListAndView("Products", "");

        string listID = listView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
        string viewID = listView.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value;

        XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement updateElement = Xdoc.CreateElement("updateElement");
        updateElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
        updateElement.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
        updateElement.SetAttribute("ViewName", viewID);

        updateElement.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>"
                                  + "<Field Name = 'ID'>" + index + "</Field>"
                                  + "<Field Name = 'Title'>" + prodTitle + "</Field>"
                                  + "<Field Name = 'Product_SKU'>" + prodSKU + "</Field>"
                                  + "<Field Name = 'Product_Price'>" + prodPrice + "</Field>"
                                  + "</Method>";

        XmlNode responseXml = myListUpdateProxy.UpdateListItems("Products", updateElement);
        MessageBox.Show(responseXml.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update items you should use [`UpdateListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) instead of `GetListItems`.  Also, when using `UpdateListItems`, wrap your `<Metdod>` tags in `<Batch>` elements.  This would be in place of your `updateElement`.  See if that works, and, if not, please include the `responseText` of the actual error message along with what version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I have done wrong is that I missed using <Batch> element and used updateElement instead of that place. When I replace the updateElement with 'Batch', everything works fine. Thanks a lot.